# FBRequest can not work in NSOperation

Tags: objective-c, facebook, block, nsoperation

Why does the line: `NSLog(@"request complete");` not work?
The code inside the block is only called when `FBRequest` is completed. I thought that in the meantime, my operation would be removed from the `NSOperationQueue` and the block wouldn't be called.

test.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface test: NSOperation;
@end
```

test.m

```
#import "test.h"
@implementation test

- (void)start {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _isExecuting = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

    [self loadFBRequest];
}

- (BOOL)isConcurrent {
    return YES;
}

- (void)finish {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

    _isExecuting = NO;
    _isFinished = YES;

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}

- (void)loadFBRequest {
    FBRequestConnection *conn = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];

    // Example: Get my info
    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"/me?fields=id,name"];
    [conn addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"result=%@", result);
        }
        NSLog(@"request complete"); // Don't work!
        [self finish];
    }];
    [conn start];
}

@end
```

Comment: I have experienced with this too. `FBRequestConnection` didn't work if not called on main thread. However it is not a big deal as the `addRequest:completionHandler:` method work asynchronously, it will not block your main thread.